# Canvas data Export fabric.js

Tags: imagemagick, fabricjs

i want to know that what is the good method to export the data for Canvas with fabric.js,
Let's say, I have four images, 123.ai, 123.eps, 123.svg, 123.jpg. Now while adding on Canvas, with imagemagick I am converting it to png, So all the images will converted to .png extension, and then with .toSvg method I am exporting the Canvas data, So in SVG i am getting the reference path of the png files only, which are converted and added to the canvas. Now Actually while opening in illustrator, SVG takes references of png files instead of original files, So is there any ways I can retain original files while using method .toSvg . So i can direct open in illustrator, While If i make any in .Ai file, so that update would automatically updated in SVG file, if it takes the reference of original files instead of converted png file.

Or is there any way i can use another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all fabric js is working perfect with illustrator saved file. So if there is any file saved with illustrator in any format will have accurate output in canvas.
Second thing, as you said, that you are also working with SVG files. So it is ideal way to add SVG files to canvas and export canvas to SVG so you will not have any reference to any PNG files. you have smooth and straight forward way that you will add SVG files and export SVG file.

Comment: Hey Innodel, Thanks for your answer, but i am little bit confused here, the canvas is not showing illustrator saved images, i.e. AI, SVG, EPS, PSD. so i am converting them to png with imagemagick and showing them onto canvas. can you suggest any links where above formats are uploaded on canvas?

Comment: canvas is not able to understand about this formats. You have to convert those images to svg and than those svgs can be loaded on canvas using fabric js `loadSVGfromURL` or `loadSVGfromString` method

Comment: but, that's the challenge, I have to function like by php i am uploading the image, and showing that image onto canvas, but dont know how can I convert that image into svg, if it is vector or raster image.

Comment: I have a also same requirement of  load vector(.eps .ai .psd etc)to canvas in fabric js according to Kangax it is first need to convert to SVG, so which is good tools for convert .eps .ai .psd to svg with PHP & linux